# Programmatic access to Export options for filetype

Tags: export, import, image, options, files-and-directories

For specific filetypes, e.g JPG, GIF, etc. I would like to get a list of available options for use in Import and Export.

Unfortunately, the obvious thing doesn’t work:

```
Options @ Export (* is {} *)
Options @ Import (* is {} *)
```

Comment: This help?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164121/38205

Comment: Long story short: ``Get@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/MiscFuncs.m";
getFormatImportData["PDF"]``

Comment: What about Export options?

Comment: `getFormatExportData["PDF"]`

Comment: Haha nice, very nice

Comment: @b3m2a1 RegisterImport and RegisterExport do not give any information about the options accepted by a particular format. There is not an easy way to do this at this time unfortunately (particularly for Options)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible in 11.3. Best bet for now is look at the ref/Format pages. We will look into ways to improve this in the future.