# CSV import with delimiters not working for certain characters (curly quotation marks)

Tags: import, csv-format

Here's an example CSV file (Example 1):

```
"Text","”","False","False","False","False","0","1","24","0","9","450","450"
```

and the code to import it (Code 1):

```
Import[filepath, "CSV"]
(* Outputs: {{"Text", "", "False", "False", "False", "False", 0, 1, 24, 0, 9, 450, 450}} *)
```

Here's another file with different delimiters (Example 2):

```
"Text"|"”"|"False"|"False"
```

And here's the code to import it (from the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50655/55405)) (Code 2):

```
Import[filepath, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> "|"]
(* Outputs: {{"Text", "â", "False", "False"}} *)
```

Either method does not seem to be correctly importing single or double quotation marks. In the example, the second value is being incorrectly imported. Weirdly enough, the following CSV file—which is just generated by copying the second value from the example—does work.

```
"”","”","”","”"
```

With different delimiters, this does not work again. What could be causing this unexpected behaviour? I tried the default CSV reader in Python and it doesn't seem to have any issues parsing the file.

---

### Question Update

Based on MarcoB's comment, I realized that different file encodings are giving different results. Here are the following outputs of the example CSV files with different file encodings:

**Example 1, ANSI:**

```
{{"Text", "", "False", "False", "False", "False", 0, 1, 24, 0, 9, 450, 450}}
```

**Example 1, UTF-8:**

```
{{"Text", "\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]", "False", "False", "False", 
  "False", 0, 1, 24, 0, 9, 450, 450}}
```

**Example 2, ANSI:**

```
{{"Text", "", "False", "False"}}
```

**Example 2, UTF-8:**

```
{{"Text", "â", "False", "False"}}
```

In summary, the only CSV file which seems to be imported correctly is the Example 1 (comma separated values, no custom delimiters), encoded in UTF-8. All other cases do not seem to work. Python is able to import all the example cases without any problems. How do I make it work for all cases? I want to be able to just specify the delimiter and let Mathematica do the rest, like in Python.

Comment: Although I am not sure that I understand the problem you have, I don't think I can reproduce any problems on my end. I copied your string into a text file, then imported it using your `Import` command, and the result was `{{"Text", "\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]", "False", "False", "False", 
  "False", 0, 1, 24, 0, 9, 450, 450}} `. That seems fine to me. What were you expecting? I am on Win10-64 and MMA 12.

Comment: @MarcoB How weird! It works now for "," delimiters, it was just showing up as some unknown blank character previously. However, the "|" delimiter still does not work (using the code above): `"Text"|"”"|"False"|"False"`

Comment: It does not work depending on the file encoding. Please see the updated the question.

Comment: When producing the output for your example, are you giving explict `CharacterEncoding` options or do you let `Import` find out the encoding itself? I wouldn't have much hope that `Import` always gets this right automatically, if it even tries to (and I'm not sure whether it does or not)...

Comment: @Albert Retey I did not specify the `CharacterEncoding`. `ANSI` appears to be a valid character encoding on the help page https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CharacterOperations.html, but I do not have it listed under `$CharacterEncodings`. Is this normal? I don't know which one to choose.

Comment: if you search the internet for "ANSI encoding" you will find evidence that this name obviously isn't well defined. According to wikipedia it most often is used (wrongly?) to actually mean "Windows-1252" and this is most probably refered to as "WindowsANSI" within Mathematica. Please don't ask me why character encodings are such a mess :-)

Comment: @AlbertRetey Lo and behold, it works! I found that both cases works with `WindowsANSI` now.

Comment: ok, great to hear it works now. If this solves your problem I think it is welcomed to add your own answer and accept it in such cases...

Comment: Thank you for figuring it out, I've added my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Albert Retey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/169/albert-retey)'s comment, I was able to get it to work by specifying the `CharacterEncoding`. I checked the file encoding using Windows' Notepad. I used the following code for the case with the pipe delimiters:

```
(* ANSI file *)
Import[filepath, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> "|", CharacterEncoding -> "WindowsANSI"];
(* UTF-8 file *)
Import[filepath, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> "|", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
```

Weirdly enough, "ANSI" is listed as a valid character encoding on the [help page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CharacterOperations.html), but it doesn't exist under `$CharacterEncodings`. On my version of Mathematica, it is named `WindowsANSI` instead.

For comma separated delimiters with the normal import method (code 1), the file encoding only needs to be specified with ANSI files, so I presume that Mathematica imports it as UTF-8. However, with custom delimiters, the file encoding has to be specified, so I'm not sure what character encoding Mathematica uses by default in that case.

---

**Update:** As [GenericAccountName](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38159/genericaccountname) recommended in the comment below, we can use the  [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) for `Table (.dat)` (under the general category "Import/Export format") to find out the default `CharacterEncoding` for importing and exporting, located under Options. Apparently the default `CharacterEncoding` used when importing is "ISOLatin1", but note that it is "UTF-8" when exporting.

As of now, looking up the documentation is probably the best method, as it appears that programmatically searching up Options for `Import`/`Export` is not implemented yet, based on this question: [Programmatic access to Export options for filetype](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190820/55405)

Comment: You could check the documentation to see what the default CharacterEncoding is. For "Table" it is ISOLatin1, and for "CSV" it is "UTF-8", falling back to ISOLatin1 if there are invalid UTF8 byte sequences.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find it here: 
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html
under Options > Import Options > CharacterEncoding. It's useful as we can see now that the default import CharacterEncoding is ISOLatin1, but the default CharacterEncoding for exporting is UTF-8.

Comment: This is for historic reasons at this point.. I think in the future it will be best to update Table to match CSV/TSV (UTF8ISOLatin1)