# How to control floating point precision when `Export`ing to obj format?

Tags: export, mesh, precision-and-accuracy

Suppose we have a `MeshRegion` that we want to export to an obj file with, say double precision. Is that possible with `Export`? And how would we do that? The documentation on `"OBJ"` does not list any options. I am asking explicitly about `Export`. Of course, I could write my own OBJ exporter, but this would be somewhat awkward. (I've actually done it already.)

The default seems to export only about 6 decimal digits as the following example is supposed to show:

```
R = MeshRegion[
   {{0., 0., 0.}, {Sqrt[2.], 0., 0.}, {0., Sqrt[2.], 0.}},
   Triangle[{{1, 2, 3}}]
   ];
file = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "a.obj"}];
Export[file, R];
MeshCoordinates[Import[file]] - MeshCoordinates[R]
```

> {{0., 0., 0.}, {-3.60048*10^-6, 0., 0.}, {0., -3.60048*10^-6, 0.}}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't have the time to fully answer this yet, but here's [a debug tool I developed previously](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164121/27951). First off we can figure out how OBJ is exported

```
getFormatExportData["OBJ"]

{"FormatName" -> "OBJ", "DefaultElement" -> "Graphics3D", 
 "DocumentedElements" -> None, "Function" -> System`Convert`OBJDump`ExportOBJ, 
 "FunctionChannels" -> {"Streams"}, "HiddenElements" -> None, 
 "Options" -> {"InvertNormals", "VerticalAxis", "Comments"}, 
 "Sources" -> \
{"/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/\
MacOSX-x86-64/Convert/Common3D.mx", 
   "/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/\
MacOSX-x86-64/Convert/OBJ.mx"}, "BinaryFormat" -> True, 
 "File" -> "/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Formats/OBJ/\
Export.m"}
```

Then we get the defs for that func (you may need to load the `.mx` first)

```
System`Convert`OBJDump`ExportOBJ // GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal

ExportOBJ[strm_, expr_, opts___] := Block[
    {res, nopts, method, a, expr1, obj},
    nopts = Flatten @ {opts};
    method = ("ImportExportMethod" /. nopts) /. {"ImportExportMethod" -> $ImportExportMethod};
nopts = DeleteCases[nopts, "ImportExportMethod" -> _];
a = Flatten[expr /. {RuleDelayed -> List}];
nopts = Union @ Flatten @ Join[nopts, Most @ a];
nopts = Select[nopts, Function[Equal[Head @ #, Rule]]];
obj = Last @ a;
expr1 = "Graphics3D" -> obj;
res = dispatchExportOBJ[method, strm, expr1, nopts];
res /; UnsameQ[res, $Failed]
];
```

Which means it's handled by `dispatchExportOBJ` and so looking at those defs we get back to either `` System`Convert`OBJDump`LegacyExportOBJ `` or `` System`Convert`OBJDump`ImprovedLgacyExportOBJ ``, the latter of which seems to delegate to `` GeometryTools`WGTAssimpExport `` and the former of which is just a bunch of `WriteString` calls which could be modified to have higher precision.

Can't get you to a full solution at this point in time though.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did mean you to dig that deeply into the internals, but I learned a lot from this. Apparently, there is no easy way to specify precision other than overwriting the library function pointed onto by ``GeometryTools`GeometryToolsDump`iWGTAssimpExport``. But then it is easier for me use my customized library functions anyways. Anyways, thank you for looking into this. have my accept!